# Grails running in Jetty renders 404 error page without layout template

Tags: grails, jetty

I've a Grails 2.0.1 application. I set up the following UrlMapping:

```
"/"(controller:"home")
"500"(view:'/error/serverError')
"404"(view:'/error/notFound')
```

This is my notFound.gsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
      <title>404 Not Found</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <h2>Page not found</h2>
      <p>Back to <a href="${createLink(uri:'/')}">homepage</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

While developing (under Tomcat) the 404 error page renders correctly main layout template.
But when I deploy the war in production under Jetty 7.6.2 and I browse to a non-existing url I get the 404 error page but *without* the main layout template.

So it seems that Grails 2.0.1 doesn't play well with Jetty and the application can't render the template when a 404 error is hit.

Anyone can guess why I'm getting this issue ? I couldn't find anything in the net.

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like it may be an unresolved Grails bug -- https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8935

Comment: Hi Igor, yes this is unresolved. I filed a bug here https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1496 and then it was reported in grails. I got a long series of unresolved grails bugs... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: http://www.javathinking.com/2007/12/404-with-grails/

Instead of going directly to the gsp, you can redirect to an ErrorController which in turn redirects to different error-pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the post you linked is exactly about my issue. But my problem is specifically with jetty because on tomcat it works fine even with the urlmapping pointing directly to the gsp. On jetty it cannot render the layout neither with the urlmapping pointing to the controller. Seems a Jetty issue.

Answer (score 0):

I manually wrapped the error page with

It's not elegant, but works.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/applyLayout.html

Comment: Hm this doesn't seem to work anymore -- still seems like the layout (and/or Grails resources) are not applied.