# Grails response.sendError not rendering gsp tags

Tags: html, css, grails

I'm trying to show a 404 whenever a user inputs an invalid id in the url.

```
def show(Hero heroInstance) {
    if (heroInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return response.sendError(404)
    }
    respond heroInstance
}
```

The 404 is mapped to a custom page_not_found in UrlMappings. However none of the css is being loaded into the page. All I get is a page with the page not found text.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="layout" content="main">
  <title>PAGE NOT FOUND</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>404</h2>

  <p>
    PAGE NOT FOUND
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to load the css using sendError?

Comment: have you written css for this page in a separate css file?

Comment: Yes. At least grails did. This is just a starter app that I'm toying around with. If I give the browser a page that doesn't exist in my app then it renders the 404 page correctly. e.g. my app's name is hello and I manually enter hello/notExistingPage it will render the 404 correctly.

Comment: Hey @AkoEliasLopezlopezlopezLopez were you ever able to resolve your issue?  I think it might be related to this issue too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657816/grails-running-in-jetty-renders-404-error-page-without-layout-template

Comment: No. We reimplemented a lot of our code so it ended up not being an issue for us. We basically just turned our backend into an API and let AngularJS call functions on that API. So grails doesn't handle our views.

Answer (score 0):

well if you have an external css i think you should add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

this to your

```
<head></head>
```

only then your css will be included into your html

or

you may give your css in the html page itself using

```
<style>
your css goes here
</style>
```